# How to add a score record system in tic tac toe Java game

Tags: java, netbeans

I am working on a tic tac toe game using java netbeans in a gui and need help adding How many wins 'x' and 'o' got. The following code is the only file i am using for this project so far. The rest of the code itself has no issues and the game works as expected, just need to add a score system. Any ideas how i can implement the score system?

```
  package game;

/**
 *
 * @author Naqash
 */

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Game extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Game() {
        initComponents();
        addAction();
    }

    public void winEffect(JButton b1, JButton b2, JButton b3){

        b1.setBackground(Color.RED);
        b2.setBackground(Color.RED);
        b3.setBackground(Color.RED);

        b1.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        b2.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        b3.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

        String msg = b1.getText() + " Won!";
        jLabelMSG.setText(msg);

    }

    boolean win = false;
    public void getTheWinner(){

        if(!jButton1.getText().equals("") && jButton1.getText().equals(jButton2.getText()) && jButton1.getText().equals(jButton3.getText())){
            winEffect(jButton1, jButton2, jButton3);
            win = true;
        }

        if(!jButton4.getText().equals("") && jButton4.getText().equals(jButton5.getText()) && jButton4.getText().equals(jButton6.getText())){
            winEffect(jButton4, jButton5, jButton6);
            win = true;
        }

        if(!jButton7.getText().equals("") && jButton7.getText().equals(jButton8.getText()) && jButton7.getText().equals(jButton9.getText())){
            winEffect(jButton7, jButton8, jButton9);
            win = true;
        }

        if(!jButton1.getText().equals("") && jButton1.getText().equals(jButton4.getText()) && jButton1.getText().equals(jButton7.getText())){
            winEffect(jButton1, jButton4, jButton7);
            win = true;
        }

        if(!jButton2.getText().equals("") && jButton2.getText().equals(jButton5.getText()) && jButton2.getText().equals(jButton8.getText())){
           winEffect(jButton2, jButton5, jButton8);
           win = true;
        }

        if(!jButton3.getText().equals("") && jButton3.getText().equals(jButton6.getText()) && jButton3.getText().equals(jButton9.getText())){
            winEffect(jButton3, jButton6, jButton9);
            win = true;
        }

        if(!jButton1.getText().equals("") && jButton1.getText().equals(jButton5.getText()) && jButton1.getText().equals(jButton9.getText())){
            winEffect(jButton1, jButton5, jButton9);
            win = true;
        }

        if(!jButton3.getText().equals("") && jButton3.getText().equals(jButton5.getText()) && jButton3.getText().equals(jButton7.getText())){
            winEffect(jButton3, jButton5, jButton7);
            win = true;
        }

        else if(allButtonsTextLength() == 9 && win == false){
            jLabelMSG.setText("Draw!");
        }
    }

    public int allButtonsTextLength(){

        String txt = "";

        Component[] comps = jPanel2.getComponents();

        for(Component comp : comps){
            if(comp instanceof JButton){
                JButton button = (JButton)comp;
                 txt = txt + button.getText();
            }
        }
        return txt.length();
    }

    int x_or_o = 0;

    public ActionListener createAction(JButton button){

        ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                if(button.getText().equals("")){
                    if((x_or_o % 2) == 0){

                            button.setText("X");
                            button.setForeground(Color.red);
                           jLabelMSG.setText("O Turn");
                            getTheWinner();
                        }else{
                            button.setText("O");
                            button.setForeground(Color.blue);
                            jLabelMSG.setText("X Turn");
                            getTheWinner();
                        }

                        x_or_o ++;
                    }

                }

            };
        return al;
        }      

    public void addAction(){

        Component[] comps = jPanel2.getComponents();

        for(Component comp : comps){
            if(comp instanceof JButton){
                JButton button = (JButton)comp;
                button.addActionListener(createAction(button));
        }
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")                
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabelMSG = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton7 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton8 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton9 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButtonReplay = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButtonEnd = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(242, 38, 19));

        jLabelMSG.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24));
        jLabelMSG.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabelMSG.setText("Start");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabelMSG, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 235, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jLabelMSG, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 67, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jButton1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 30));

        jButton2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 30));

        jButton3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jButton3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 30));

        jButton4.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jButton4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 30));

        jButton5.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jButton5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 30));

        jButton6.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jButton6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 30));

        jButton7.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jButton7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 30));

        jButton8.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jButton8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 30));

        jButton9.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jButton9.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 30));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 81, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 81, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 81, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 81, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 81, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 81, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 81, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 81, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 81, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 80, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 80, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 80, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 80, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 80, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 80, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jButton7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 80, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 80, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 80, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
        );

        jButtonReplay.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255,0,0));
        jButtonReplay.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 36));
        jButtonReplay.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jButtonReplay.setText("Restart");
        jButtonReplay.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButtonReplayActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButtonEnd.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255,0,0));
        jButtonEnd.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 36));
        jButtonEnd.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jButtonEnd.setText("End Game");
        jButtonEnd.addActionListener(new CloseListener());


        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addContainerGap())
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(jButtonReplay, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 265, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButtonEnd, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 265, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jButtonReplay, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jButtonEnd, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGap(20, 20, 20))
        );

        pack();
    }                     

    private void jButtonReplayActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              

        win = false;        
        Component[] comps = jPanel2.getComponents();

        for(Component comp : comps){
            if(comp instanceof JButton){
                JButton button = (JButton)comp;
                button.setText("");
                button.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                jLabelMSG.setText("Start");
            }
        }

    }                                             

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Game.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Game.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Game.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Game.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Game().setVisible(true);
            }
        });


    }

    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton7;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton8;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton9;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButtonReplay;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabelMSG;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButtonEnd;

    void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

}
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Take a tour and get your first badge-https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Well, first you're going to need some variables to keep track of the scoring information; second, you'll need to add some code that actually updates those variables appropriately at the end of a game; and third, you'll need to provide somewhere on your GUI to display the scoring information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this via a `JLabel` and a method to support the winner logic.

```
int xWinCount = 0;
int oWinCount = 0;

private void incrementWinner( String winner )
{
    if( "X".equals( winner ) )
    {
        xWinCount += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        oWinCount += 1;
    }
}
```

And then call this in your `winEffect` method as below.

```
    incrementWinner( b1.getText() );
    jLabelWinner.setText( "X wins : " + xWinCount + " | O wins : " + oWinCount );
```

`jLabelWinner` is defined in the `initComponent` method as below

```
jLabelWinner = new javax.swing.JLabel();
jLabelWinner.setFont( new java.awt.Font( "Tahoma", 1, 18 ) );
jLabelWinner.setText( "Win Status" );
```

And then, add this to the layout.

```
layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup( javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING )
                      .addGroup( layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                       .addContainerGap()
                                       .addGroup( layout.createParallelGroup( javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING )
                                                        .addComponent( jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE )
                                                        .addGroup( layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                                         .addComponent( jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE )
                                                                         .addGap( 0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE ) ) )
                                       .addContainerGap() )
                      .addGroup( layout.createParallelGroup( javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING )
                                       .addComponent( jButtonReplay, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 265, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE )
                                       .addComponent( jButtonEnd, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 265, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE ) )
                      .addComponent( jLabelWinner, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 265, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE )
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup( javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING )
                      .addGroup( layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                       .addContainerGap()
                                       .addComponent( jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE )
                                       .addPreferredGap( javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED )
                                       .addComponent( jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE )
                                       .addGap( 18, 18, 18 )
                                       .addComponent( jButtonReplay, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE )
                                       .addGap( 18, 18, 18 )
                                       .addComponent( jButtonEnd, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE )
                                       .addGap( 18, 18, 18 )
                                       .addComponent( jLabelWinner, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE )
                                       .addGap( 20, 20, 20 ) )
        );
```

Styling and reseting is up to you. This is one way to do what you want

Answer (score 0):

To do this you can use two integers which will hold the score of each player and display them somehow on the screen, for this I just printed out the score in the console, but you can do whatever you like. The resulting print message is:

```
Current score:
X = 1 VS O = 0
```

Heres the code:

```
//Add the two integers to hold them, in my IDE this shows line 14
int xScore = 0, oScore = 0;
```

Then you increase the value of the integers when a win is detected, i did this adding the following lines of code in your `winEffect()` method. I also disabled the buttons when a win is called so that theu cannot keep adding Xs or Os even after the game has ended, and this also prevents the method from being trigerred again, which would increase the score again. im my IDE this shows line 29, it is the end of the winEffect:

```
if (b1.getText().equals("X")) xScore++;
else if (b1.getText().equals("O")) oScore++;

for (Component comp : jPanel2.getComponents())
    if (comp instanceof JButton)
        comp.setEnabled(false);

System.out.printf("Current score:\n X = %d VS O = %d\n\n", xScore, oScore);
```

After that, you need to reenable the buttons when the restart button is pressed, so inside your `jButtonReplayActionPerformed()` method I reenabled them using the following, in my IDE this shows line 309:

```
for(Component comp : comps){
    if(comp instanceof JButton){
        JButton button = (JButton)comp;
        button.setText("");
        button.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        jLabelMSG.setText("Start");
        button.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```